# when sending json request to server I am getting forbidden 403

Tags: jmeter

I am learning jmeter.

I am passing json request in Body of http request. I set content-type as application/json. passing cookie value using cookie manager.  I am getting response code as 403. how to resolve it??

I have passed all the headers which is caputred in Firebug..  Only the difference is the captured cookie  in the firebug has lot of values but when i run the test, the below only is passing (if I use, Cookie Manager) other than that all are same.. No clue why it is returning 403..

Cookie Data:
connect.sid=s%3AFBcljlVYI2p1WyjuxcDgWQKJ.kSrLYIsSy9T%2FEgSB25yUq0T3qTjpqF69GJhyW9GzJpU; TOKEN=ZU3cf9fKGCPJXM6qi7JX6DVv2%2B3Jw8q%2Flnb2A%3D

[image]

Comment: 403 means forbidden, that means some value you are supposed to pass is missing. Probably you need to pass some token value in the request header.

Comment: Hi JmeterPerfTest, Can you just check i have added more info regarding thii issue..

Comment: have you made the token extraction dynamic??

Comment: Token is automatically taken by the Cookie Manager.. I checked it and it is taken correctly from the server response on each request

Comment: but do you update the new value generated in your cookie for the parameter "***TOKEN***" in your ***HTTP Request Header***?

Comment: Your Snapshot shows, mismatch of value. The Token set in ***COOKIE*** is ***different*** for the value of ***TOKEN*** in ***HTTP Request Header***.

Comment: Yes..connect.sid and Token is automatically handled by Cookie Manager.. it is getting updated whatever the new value generated...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65197/discussion-between-changan-and-jmeter-perftest).

Comment: Can you help me on this?

Comment: I have updated some details in Chat

Comment: I have replied in the chat. can you check

Answer (score 0):

403 is a "Forbidden" error.  Most likely is that something needs to be sent in the body of your http request, like a token, which needs to be extracted from the log in request.

Answer (score 0):

Add Http authorization manager, specify the url along with the crednetials in it. Keep the encoding mechanism to BASIC_DIGEST. Enable log viewer so that you can trace the exact issue